# The definition of "is not valid"

Tags: qgis, parameters, proj4js

When I validate the proj4 parameters it says they are valid but when I press OK I get the above error message. My parameters are:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-117 +k=1 +x_0=-64830 +y_0=-5264340 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs +type=crs
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this too. It's not a problem with your new CRS, it's because QGIS automatically adds a blank entry when you open the dialog. So when you hit the plus button, you are technically adding a SECOND CRS, and QGIS is telling you that the first one is invalid. Just click in the white space above your new added one and delete the blank line. Highlighted blue in the attached image.

[image: Custom CRS blank line highlighted]

Comment: I had the same problem but unfortunately this fix didn't work. (It did however work when I used the proj string instead of WKT)